# listening for click event in a form from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

ok so I have a form with a button and a combobox,when the form loads I start a new thread. In that thread I want to listen for the click event from the form and get the selected item from the combobox. Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Show the code you have, that makes it easier to answer.

Comment: You cannot listen for an event that's raised on the UI thread in code that runs on another thread.  Obviously you can implement a Click event handler and get it to do *anything*.  Like signaling a thread. Or plain start one.  A thread is much to expensive to waste on something that happens at human-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do some long running CPU expensive processing on button click, i would recommend to start a new thread every time the button is clicked. The best way would be to listen the click event in the main thread, and when the event fires - start a new thread and pass selected value there.

Comment: Awesome!!  I think this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't strictly 'listen' to an event in C#. What you are doing when you attach an event handler to a control is providing a method (as a delegate) that you would like called when the event occurs. Your method will be invoked on whatever thread the invoking class decides to call it on, typically the same thread that the cause of the event happened on. For Windows Forms controls, this is always the UI thread.

In your event handler, you could (and often should) call another method to do the actual work, on another thread. There are many ways of doing this, from manually starting a thread, to the thread pool, to using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to have just one thread, that you control, processing all the events, the best idea is having a producer-consumer relationship. Have a queue into which your event handler places an instruction to do work, and have a thread which takes items out of the queue and processes them.

To signal your worker thread to know when there is new work, you can look into [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).